# not able to understand the testing condition in the loop

Tags: c++

```
for (int g=1; g<=100000; g++)
{
    for (int y=0; y<20; y++)
    {
        if ( ((1<<y)&g) && (!((1<<(y+1))&g)) && ((1<<(y+2))&g) ) counter[g]++; 
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what this if condition is checking but am still confused, is it checking for 101? 
Can anyone explain what this if condition is testing for?

Comment: Ever heard about bit shifting operators and bitwise AND?

Comment: Try to split it up into smaller and smaller pieces, until it's not possible to split anymore. Then use a debugger to check the result of each simple and small sub-expression.

Comment: That `if` statement is desperately calling out for a named function as its predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner cycle finds the number of `101` (possibly intersected) bit patterns among the least 22 bits of `g`. And the condition could be replaced with

```
if (((g >> i) & 0b111) == 0b101) counter[g]++;
```

Comment: Plus one. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. (I'm too old for this.)

Comment: Maximum value of `y` is 19, so `1<<(y+2)` shifts by 21 (so the 22nd bit is checked)